# Is energy affected by forces?

Tags: forces, energy

Curious, is any certain form of energy, such as heat, affected by a force? Can you push energy from one place to another?

Update: An example case: Now suppose we have a solid medium by which energy can propagate. If there is energy in a specific region of the solid, can I move that energy to another specific region of that solid? How?

Comment: It's more accurate to say gravity is affected by energy.  Specifically, the stress-energy tensor.  If you heated a rod, there would be an increased gravitational force (albeit negligible) between the rod and the black hole.  Also, black holes are not anti-matter.  That is something different.

Comment: For all you people in the future: Question was originally "Is energy affected by gravity?"

Comment: I extended my answer. I am sorry if you didn't get the answer you wanted - this time it will be maybe better.

Comment: Are you looking for a simple answer about the relationship between energy "bookkeeping" for and object and a force acting on an object, or is the whole spacetime curvature, Einstein Field Equation what you wanted?

Comment: Never did I mention once about an object or force acting on an(other) object. I mentioned force acting on energy. Also it seems quite paradoxical in the fact that force requires energy, so then again, I must be asking if you can push energy with energy, like you can fight fire with fire.

Comment: According to the [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) any form of energy translates into mass, and since masses are affected by forces so are energies. And yes, it takes energy to move energy, but energy can be moved without any material movement, e.g. by acoustic waves. However, in addition to moving energy can also be converted from one form into another, which also requires energy but does not necessarily involve movement.

Comment: @Conifold ok, that makes sense, now put it in an answer please so I can confirm it.// Aren't all forms of energy really the same energy?

Answer (score 1):

If you heat that rod, its mass will grow, and thus its weight too. But the difference is unmeasurable low (practically, the rod will lost much more mass by its fastened vaporization). You had to heat it to milliards of Kelvins to grow its mass with some thousadths.

Such things are handled by the [EFE (Einstein Field Equations)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations). These equations are defining the relation between the curvature of the spacetime and the mass in it. The curvature of the spacetime is what we sense as gravity in our circumstance. And every form of energy has its mass, based on the [mass-energy equivalence principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence), this is the well-known $E=mc^2$ relation, which essentially says: $1kg = 9\times 10^{16}J$.

This black hole thing on the end I simply don't understand, I suggest to fragment that into smaller questions and ask them more elaborated, again.

*Extension after question edit:*

The EFE describes the relation between the energy density and the spacetime curvature. Here counts *any type of energy*, thermical energy just as normal matter (which is counted by the mass-energy equivalence). Thus the answer is yes, gravitation affects energy. Although if you calculate, how many energy has the mass of a rod weighting $1 kg$ ($9\times 10^{16} J$) or, how many thermical energy will it have if you heat this with $1000K$ (some ten-thousands of $J$), you can see that in normal circumstances only the rest mass which really counts.

In case of the other interactions, the situation is more complex. It is handled by the quantum mechanics, which doesn't operates with forces, but with virtual bosons. You can imagine that as if, for example, the attraction and the distraction between a proton and electron were handled by photons emitted by the particles.