# existence of energy in absence of force?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, forces, energy

1)Does energy to be precise potential energy exist without the presence of a force?
2)Can kinetic energy also be viewed as another form of potential energy?

Comment: Related:http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145619/is-energy-affected-by-forces?rq=1

Comment: it doesn't answer my particular question.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of a field?

Comment: I have studied high school electrostatics and magnetism.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any traditional potential energy that doesn't involve a force.

For the energy to be potential and not in some other form, the force is being resisted by whatever is maintaining the potential.  If the force were no longer restrained by an opposite force (like if the second story floor you were standing on disappeared) then the potential energy would be released as another form of energy (often kinetic energy or energy dissipated from resistance) .

I wouldn't say kinetic can be viewed as another form of potential energy in most cases.  You might be able to argue that a little bit in the case of a gas in a closed container.  In that case you can give the gas kinetic energy by heating it up, which will increase the pressure in the closed container.  The thing is, it's only potential energy if you consider the container and the fluid (since the container walls are applying force to resist the pressure).  If you consider just the gas it still only has kinetic energy.

So I guess I can't think of any examples of it if it does indeed happen; this interpretation is all from classical mechanics by the way.

Comment: but can energy in general exist without force??